Hypercube and straight line intersection
We have a hypercube H of dimension $n\geq 3$. We say L a straight line that goes through H and NOT through any vertex of H and any edge of H (edges are facets of H of dimension $1$, that is the segment between two adjacent vertices).
The question is: if we move L along a direction perpendicular to L, is L going to intersect at least an edge of H?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

If $n=3$, the answer is yes.  If we move $L$ in the direction $u$, perpendicular to $L$, then there will be minimum and maximum values of $\lambda$ such that $L+\lambda u$ intersects $H$.  In particular $L+\lambda u$ will not intersect the interior of more than one face.  Thus either it lies along a face, and intersects at least two of the edges of that face, or it intersects a single edge.
Conversely, if $n>3$ then $L+\lambda u$ need not intersect any edge.  We give an example when $n=4$, which generalises naturally to arbitrary dimension $n>3$.
Let $H\subset \mathbb{R}^4$ have vertices $(\pm1,\pm1,\pm1,\pm1)$.  Let $L=\{(\mu,0,0,0)|\, \mu\in\mathbb{R}\}$, and let $u=(0,1,0,0)$. Then at most two co-ordinates of a point in $L+\lambda u$ will be $\pm1$.  However a point on an edge of $H$ would have at least three such co-ordinates.  Thus  $L+\lambda u$ does not intersect any edge of $H$.
Geometrically, think of a hypercube as a union of cubical slices at different heights in the fourth dimension.  Then if our line remains at medium height in the fourth dimension, as we move it out of its cubical slice, it will not hit any vertices of its cubical slice, only edges.  However edges of its cubical slice are just a slice of a face of $H$, not edges of $H$, as the cubical slice is at medium height.
Nice question - slightly counter intuitive visually.

Thank you for the answer. If I add the constraint $u=(0,\neq 0,\neq 0,0)$, the answer is yes, are you agree?

If $H\subset \mathbb{R}^4$ has vertices $(\pm1,\pm1,\pm1,\pm1)$ and $L={(\mu,0,0,0)|, \mu\in\mathbb{R}}$, and you add the constraint $u=(0,x,y,0)$ with $x,y\neq 0$ then both possibilities can occur: If $x=y$ the line and hypercube will intersect at the edge point $(1,1,1,0)$ for example.  Conversely, if $x\neq\pm y$, then $L$ will not intersect any edge of $H$.
